# Flutter - DropdownButtonFormField Padding - Exception Caught by Rendering Library

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to add padding horizontally to a row with two dropdowns...

And here what it looks like before I add padding.

[image]

And here's my code.

```
class _ProductDetailState extends State<ProductDetail> {
  String? taxStatus;
  String? taxPercentage;

  Widget _taxStatusDrop() {
    return DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
      value: taxStatus,
      hint: const Text('Select Tax Status'),
      items: ['Taxable', 'Not Taxable']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (String? value) {
        setState(() {
          taxStatus = value;
        });
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null) {
          return 'Tax Status is required';
        }
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _taxPercentageDrop() {
    return DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
      value: taxPercentage,
      hint: const Text('Select Tax Percentage'),
      items:
          ['GST-10%', 'GST-12%'].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
      onChanged: (String? value) {
        setState(() {
          taxPercentage = value;
        });
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value == null) {
          return 'Tax Percentage is required';
        }
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: _taxStatusDrop()),
              const SizedBox(width: 20),
              Expanded(child: _taxPercentageDrop()),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

After adding the padding of 18 I'm getting an exception...

[image]

And the exception saying...

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown during layout:
A RenderFlex overflowed by 14 pixels on the right.

The relevant error-causing widget was:
  DropdownButtonFormField<String>
  DropdownButtonFormField:file:///E:/Kvu/StudioProjects/shop_app_vendor/lib/screens/all_products/product_details_scree  n.dart:244:12

To inspect this widget in Flutter DevTools, visit:
http://127.0.0.1:9101/#/inspector?uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A59207%2FAYHxzH5XdOs%3D%2F&inspectorRef=inspector-0     

The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal.
The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
like a ListView.
The specific RenderFlex in question is: RenderFlex#2b0f1 OVERFLOWING:
  creator: Row ← Padding ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← DefaultTextStyle ← _Decorator ← InputDecorator
    ← Listener ← RawGestureDetector ← GestureDetector ← Semantics ← MouseRegion ← ⋯
  parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0) (can use size)
  constraints: BoxConstraints(w=168.4, h=24.0)
  size: Size(168.4, 24.0)
  direction: horizontal
  mainAxisAlignment: spaceBetween
  mainAxisSize: min
  crossAxisAlignment: center
  textDirection: ltr
  verticalDirection: down
◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

And here's my code after adding padding...

```
Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(child: _taxStatusDrop()),
            const SizedBox(width: 20),
            Expanded(child: _taxPercentageDrop()),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  )
```

### Is this something wrong with my phone screen or something else?

### How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just put isExpanded Property into your both DropdownButtonFormField,

```
  Widget _taxPercentageDrop() {
    return DropdownButtonFormField<String>(

      isExpanded: true,
```